# How do I make a button appear bigger while hovering over it with the cursor using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make these buttons get bigger when the cursor is hovering over them

```
<div>

    <li>button1</li>
    <li>button2</li>
    <li>button3</li>

</div>

<stlye>
    li:hover{
        /* What do I put in here? */
    }
</stlye>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show your relevant code.

Comment: You could try `li:hover { transform: scale(1.5); }`. Refer [MDN link here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)

Comment: Not to be nit picking but a `li` is technically no `button` and needs a `ul` or `ol` as a mandatory parent

Answer (score 4):

#### A Simple example will be:

Use `font-size: 20px;` or `font-size: 2em;`

```css
li:hover {
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>

    <li>button1</li>
    <li>button2</li>
    <li>button3</li>

</div>
```

#### A better approach will be:

`transform: scale(1.25) perspective(1px)`

```css
li {
  margin-left: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: green;
  transform: scale(1.25) perspective(1px)
}
```

```html
<div>
    <li>button1</li>
    <li>button2</li>
    <li>button3</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Such a simple answer.

Comment: @OwlheaD oh, please accept the answer, click the green checkmark, also it gives you 2 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

For a list it's good practice to put it inside of a ul element (unordered list) or ol element (ordered list).

In CSS select your list elements, followed by `:hover`

So like this:

`li:hover { font-size: 2em; }`

& voila it works.

But I recommend you to learn more about CSS and HTML. The basics are really easy & fun to learn :)

```css
ul > li {
 list-style: none; 
}

ul > li:hover {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>button1</li>
    <li>button2</li>
    <li>button3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with cimple CSS i believe,

CSS:

```
mydiv:hover {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

but you may need to use javascript, heres an example with javascript:

```
function onhover1() {
  mydiv=document.getElementById("mydiv")
  setTimeout(function() {mydiv.width="5px"}, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {mydiv.width="10px"}, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {mydiv.width="15px"}, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {mydiv.width="20px"}, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {mydiv.width="25px"}, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {mydiv.width="30px"}, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {mydiv.width="35px"}, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {mydiv.width="40px"}, 500);
}
```

then you would need the opposite for not hovering
and the button would then be like:

```
<li id="mydiv" onmouseover="onhover1()" onmouseout="onunhover1()">button|</li>
```

Comment: yeah, i know im in a struggle for time right now. its so it does not change to 40px immediatly, it will transform within 3-4 seconds 5px every .5 seconds

Answer (score -2):

```css
#container li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #d11b34;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
  -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
}

#container li:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.07);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.05, 1.07);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>button1</li>
    <li>button2</li>
    <li>button3</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: OK! who downvoted my answer here.  I've looked at all the others and it seems this one is the only 'correct' answer.  Am i missing something?  Can anyone explain?

Answer (score -2):

```css
<style> 
li: hover {
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div>

    <li>button1</li>
    <li>button2</li>
    <li>button3</li>

</div>
```

Comment: Why adding another answer which adds nothing to previous answers?